# Hostname says "This folder is empty"

Tags: windows, samba

There are two Samba servers on the network and two Windows clients. Both servers allow guest access. All four devices are part of WORKGROUP.

Computer A:

- Sees Server 1 in Explorer

  - Can access Server 1 via hostname
- Does not see Server 2 in Explorer

  - But can still access Server 2 via hostname

Computer B:

- Sees Server 1 in Explorer

  - Can access Server 1 via hostname
- Does not see Server 2 in Explorer

  - Lists no shares when accessing Server 2 via hostname ("This folder is empty"). But can access it via IP.

I tried setting up a virtual Windows machine on Computer B to see how it behaved and it was able to access Server 2 and see the shares.

Why does Computer B not list the shares? I'm thinking it must be a setting on that system that prevents it.

Comment: Provide the hosts file for both systems?

Comment: @Ramhound It's empty for both Computer A and Computer B. Only the default comments in there.